# How to block the user interface while doing a treatment in a windows store app

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, store

I have a problem with a Windows Store app.

I have a view; on this view I display data that can be modified in this view.
Once the user finishes modifying the information, they have to click on a "Finish" button to store in a database the information.

But when there is too much information to store the treatment takes a long time and the UI is open to user actions. If the user makes an action, my application throws an exception because data were not present any more for the control.

So I searched for a way to block the UI (like a `messagedialog`: Wait while your data is being stored). I tried with a message dialog, but once I tap on `yes` my storage method is launched and the message dialog is directly closed, so the user can create an exception with his action.

My question is: how to block the UI while doing a treatment in Windows Store apps?

Answer (score 0):

You can do the trick by adding the `Grid` on whole page content with, for example, `ProgressBar`. Then show it when you perform long operations and you want to avoid user interactions with the app. When operation finished, just change state of your page (hide `Grid` from the top).

The other way to do it, if you don't have a lot of elements of UI to block, is to set `IsHitTestVisible` property of your `Button`s and other clickable elements to `false` when you perform operations.

Comment: Thank for your answer, The first solution worked for me, but i think it's not really good to trick to block UI, and i got too much elements to block (~25-30) that's why i search a solution which looks like a Message Dialog.
But if there isn't other solutions i gonna use the trick.